# Wordpress load post details and content via ajax in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have stored the post-id info in a `data-*` attribute, I wish to display this content in a div via `&.ajax()` function. 
this is the code I'm working on.

1. A list item that display the post thumb

   ```
   <li class="homus-partners-section-single" data-post-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
       <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
   </li>
   ```
2. the div where i want to display the item

   ```
   <div class="homus-partners-detalis">
       <div class="homus-partners-detalis-img">
           <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
       </div>
       <div class="homus-partners-detalis-info">
           <h4>
               <?php the_title(); ?>
           </h4>
           <p>
               <?php the_content(); ?>
           </p>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. the ajax function

   ```
   $(document).delegate('li.homus-partners-section-single', 'click', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var pb_post_id = $(this).data('post-id');
       var data = {
           'action': 'GetPost',
           postURL : pb_post_id,
       };
       $.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) {
           $( '.homus-partners-detalis' ).html(response);
       });

   });
   ```
4. the php function

   ```
   function GetPost(){
       $cat = $_POST['catURL'];
       get_template_part($cat);
       exit();
   }
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPost', 'GetPost');
   ```

---

EDIT 2

now my code look like this but i have no answer

1. markup of the clickable element

   ```
   <li class="homus-partners-section-single" data-post-slug="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
   ```
2. div where i want to display the item

   ```
    <div class="homus-partners-detalis">
      <?php get_template_part('single_pb_post_details'); ?>
    </div>
   ```
3. php i'm calling in the div

   ```
     <div class="homus-partners-detalis-img">
       <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="homus-partners-detalis-info">
    <h4>
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h4>
    <p>
     <?php homus_excerpt('homus_pb_excerpt'); ?>
   </p>
   </div>
   ```
4. ajax function

   ```
    $(document).delegate('li.homus-partners-section-single', 'click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var pb_post_slug = $(this).data('post-slug');
     var data  = {
     'action': 'GetPostDetails',
      postURL : "single_pb_post_details.php?slugid="+ pb_post_slug,
     };
    $.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) {
       $( '.homus-partners-detalis' ).html(response);
       alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);

    });

   });
   ```
5. the php function

   ```
   function GetPostDetails(){
      $details = $_POST['postURL'];
      get_template_part($details);
   exit();
   }
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPostDetails', 'GetPostDetails');
   ```

Comment: Your `GetPost` will only return, what? You need to put something to output there, so that there is something in the `response` of the ajax call...

Comment: This: `.load("../single_pb_post_details.php?slugid=" + pb_post_slug);` Is not a good way to load your `.php` file. Use [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) instead.

Comment: i edited the php functin like this `function GetPostDetails(){
    $details = $_POST['postURL'];
    get_template_part($details);
    exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPost', 'GetPostDetails');` but the only answere i have is a zero

Comment: 0 usually happens if you didn't use `die()` or `exit()` in your output (the php function that you call in ajax).

Comment: i removed the `exit();` but the answer is still zero

Comment: You **need** `exit()`. The answer is 0 because you're not outputting anything. [Read here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for more info

Comment: ok, i read the ajax docs but i can't figure out why i still have no aswer

Comment: If you are logged in, wordpress will use `add_action('wp_ajax_GetPostDetails', 'GetPostDetails');` (*without* nopriv), so you do have to add that to your code even it doesn't solve your problem. I also recommend putting a `die('test');` before `get_template_part`. If 'test' is echoed the problem is in your template.

Comment: @FelipeElia it display test but i'm not logged in

Comment: @NicolaBertelloni if it displays test your problem isn't in ajax, but in the `single_pb_post_details.php` file. Delete the `die('test');` in your `GetPostDetails` function and put a `die('test-file');` in the first line of the `single_pb_post_details` file. Is it echoed?

Comment: @FelipeElia nope, i think the problem is in the string where i build the url  `         postURL : "single_pb_post_details.php?slug="+ pb_post_slug `

Comment: @FelipeElia that lines refers to a line in my php function  `    $pb_details = $_POST['postURL']; `

Comment: Try removing the parameter and passing it as another jQuery `data` attribute (get it's value with $_POST inside your template file). Maybe WP is trying to find a file named as `single_pb_post_details.php?slugid=XYZ` instead of looking for just `single_pb_post_details.php`.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong: for `get_template_part` the name shouldn't have `.php`! Pass just `single_pb_post_details`, without extension.

Comment: doesn't display anything but i have no error either, so maybe the error is in my php single_pb_post_details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104856/discussion-between-felipe-elia-and-nicola-bertelloni).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `get_template_part` just accepts the name of the file *without* extension, in the comments we've reached this code:

```
$(document).delegate('li.homus-partners-section-single', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var pb_post_slug = $(this).data('post-slug');
    var data  = {
        'action': 'GetPostDetails',
        postURL : "single_pb_post_details",
        post_id : pb_post_slug
    };
    $.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) {
        $( '.homus-partners-detalis' ).html(response);
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

the php code that responds to ajax request:

```
function GetPostDetails(){
    get_template_part($_POST['postURL']);
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_GetPostDetails', 'GetPostDetails');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPostDetails', 'GetPostDetails');
```

and in the template file you can check the `post_id` value with:

```
$_POST['post_id'];
```

Comment: @FelipeWlia helped me out, but we can't figure out why the post content is still not displayng

Comment: Why is there `$_POST['postURL']` inside of `get_template_part` ?

Comment: @Daniel this is quite old... if OP doesn't intend to reuse it for another stuff, that var would have always the same value, so he could call `get_template_part( 'single_pb_post_details' );`. I hope @NicolaBertelloni had found his way to the right answer...